# split and assign in one statement in Perl

Tags: perl

```
@temp = split(/\./, $_);
$val = $temp[1];
$val =~ s/\D//;
```

What is the correct syntax to write a single statement instead of these three statements in Perl?

```
($val = split(/\./, $_)[1]) =~ s/\D//;
```

gives me

> syntax error at test.pl line 126, near ")["
>
> Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's how:

```
$_="ab123.ab456cd.78";
($val = (split(/\./))[1])=~ s/\D//g;
print $val;
```

(I took the liberty of using the implicit `$_` in `split`, and adding the `/g` tag to the `s///` because removing one non-digit from the front didn't make much sense.)

Now you know this, *don't do it*. It's not clear to read, it doesn't show your intensions, and it's horrible. Much clearer is:

```
$val = (split /\./)[1];
$val =~ s/\D//g;
```

Code isn't just written for the computer. It's written for people to read in order that they can later modify it. If you don't write nice code for the next guy (who could be *you* in 2 months time), the next guy will have a horrible time figuring out what you did.

Comment: @Jonathan: quite. good programmers should know the bad uses of a language, and why not to use them. So we must teach learners bad examples as well as good.

Answer (score 9):

A list slice looks like `(LIST)[LIST]`; you've omitted the `()` part.

```
($val = (split(/\./, $_))[1]) =~ s/\D//;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here it is:

```
(my $val = (split /\./)[1]) =~ s/\D//;
```

Did you mean `\D+`, by any chance?

Test:

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;
$_ = "22.99grams";
(my $val = (split /\./)[1]) =~ s/\D+//;
print "$val\n";
```

Comment: Yes, I meant to remove all the non digits from the string (`/g` dos the job).